# If Set A and B are denumerable, then A union B is also Denumerable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I know Set A is denumerable if there exists a bijection to the natural numbers f: A -> N. Same story for B.Then A union B has no repeats, and I know all elements in A and B go to unique Natural number, so there exists a bijection from A union B to the Natural numbers as well as it essentially has all elements of A and B with no repeats, each of those elements being mapped to a natural number.

Is this the correct way to go about this?

Comment: "I know all elements in A and B go to unique Natural number" What about the elements of $A\cap B$?

Answer (score 1):

Let us first define a set $C = B\backslash A$ so that $C\cap A = \emptyset$ and $A\cup C = A\cup B$. Since $A,B$ (and consequently $C$) are countable, there exists bijections from $\mathbb{N}$, namely $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$ and $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow C$.

Define $h:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A\cup B = \begin{cases}f(\frac{n+1}{2}) \text{ if } n \text{ is odd } \\ g(\frac{n}{2})\hspace{4mm}\text{ if } n \text{ is even }\\ \end{cases}$

Then $A\cup B$ is countable.

Comment: If A=N\{1} and B=N, then B\A = {1} and does not biject with N. Therefore g:N->C is not necessarily bijective.

Answer (score 1):

If $A,B$ are two disjoint countable sets, since the set of odd natural numbers $O$ and also the set of even natural numbers $E$ are countable there are two bijections $A\equiv O$, $B\equiv E$. Hence $A\cup B \equiv O \cup E= \mathbb N$.

Comment: This is only valid when A, B are disjoint sets

Comment: Yes, I think the question asker needs a geometric picture according to his question, so proving this fact using formulas might not help

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma:** If there are $h,r$ functions such that $h:X\to Y$ and $r:Y\to X$ are injective, then there is a bijection between $X$ and  $Y$.

Having this lemma: Suppose $f:A\to \mathbb{N}$ and $g:B\to \mathbb{N}$ are bijections.

Then, $h:\mathbb{N}\to A\cup B $ defined by $h(n)=f^{-1}(n)$ is injective.

Let $r:A\cup B\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by $r(x)=\max\{2f(x),2g(x)+1\}$, to be more precise:
$$r(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}2f(x)&  x\in A\setminus B\\
2g(x)+1&  x\in B\setminus A\\
\max\{2f(x),2g(x)+1\}& x\in A\cap B
\end{array}\right.$$
Convince yourself that $r(x)$ is injective since $g,f$ are in injective and an odd number never equals an even number.

Since $h,r$ are injective, there should be a bijection between $A\cup B $ and $\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0):

If $\emptyset\ne S\subset \Bbb N$ and $S$ has no largest member then there is a bijection $e:S\to \Bbb N.$ E.g. for $s\in S$ let $e(s)=n$ iff $\{t\in S: t\le s\}$ is bijective with $\{m\in \Bbb N:m\le n\}.$ (I.e. $e(s)=n$ iff $\{t\in S:t\le s\}$  has exactly $n$ members.)

Let $f:A\to \Bbb N$ and $g:B\to \Bbb N$ be bijections. Since $A\cup B=A\cup (B$ \ $A),$ and since $A,\, (B$ \ $A)$ are disjoint, we can define an injective $h:A\cup B\to \Bbb N$ by:

$h(a)=2^{f(a)}$ for $a\in A$ and $h(b)=3^{g(b)}$ for $b\in B$ \ $A.$

Now with $S=\{h(x):x\in A\cup B\}$ let $e:S\to \Bbb N$ be a bijection.

Finally let $i(x)=e(h(x))$ for $x\in A\cup B .$ Then $i:A\cup B\to \Bbb N$ is a bijection.